# Adding Cat6 & FType To Wall

Tags: wiring, walls, data-wiring

I know you can buy plates that have 2 Cat6 connectors and 1 FType, or 1 Cat6 and 1 Ftype - but what I am needing is 4 Cat6 and 1Ftype, I know that is an odd number so I would settle for 5 Cat6 and 1 F Type.

Since I see no plates already made this way, is there a way to "crate my own" that will give me this setup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Buy a 6-port keystone jack plate, one blank (or plate may include 5 blanks) and the other connectors you want - it's a modular system. You click in the jacks you want.

Comment: And I would just need to add in 5 Cat6 Keystone Jack and 1 Modular F Type Keystone Jack?  Is that accurate?

Comment: @StarsFlyFreeFromCozyNights -- you can even add 4 keystone 8P8Cs and one F-type, and leave one slot blank

Comment: There are blank port covers so an unused port is not an open hole - often those are included with multi-port covers, if not, they are quite inexpensive. You put in the ports you need, plug the rest, and can reconfigure later if your needs change.